# How to plot two proportions over time in the same chart?

Tags: r

I am trying to analyze how two proportions change over time using a stacked bar chart where the height of the bar = % positive (var = percent) for that year and the proportional area inside of the bar represents the % of age group (var = age_prop for agegroup) in that year.
[image: snip of my data]

```
barchart <- (ggplot(data, aes(x=year, fill=age_prop, y=percent))
                + geom_bar(position='stack', stat='identity')
                + theme_bw()
                + theme(axis.text=element_text(size=16), axis.title=element_text(size=18),
                        legend.title=element_text(size=16), legend.text=element_text(size=14))
                + labs(x='Year', y='Percent')
)
```

but this is what I get:
[image]

The bar height is incorrect (for 2005, it should be 47.5%) and the bar area proportions are incorrect, even if I use fill=agegroup

Any advice is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example please? you can use the function `dput(YOURDATA)` or `dput(head(YOURDATA, n = 20))` to provide a sample.
Looks like this might help though: http://t-redactyl.io/blog/2016/01/creating-plots-in-r-using-ggplot2-part-4-stacked-bar-plots.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need

```
aes(x=year, fill=agegroup, y=percent*age_prop/100)
```